# 'take advantage of' or 'taking advantage of'?

Tags: grammar

I have the following sentences.

> 1. The cars underwent fast changes from the application of mechanical technology to digital that currently **take advantage of** artificial intelligence.
> 2. The cars underwent fast changes from the application of mechanical technology to digital that currently **taking advantage of** artificial intelligence.

I am not sure, which sentence is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that even for a learners' site, this question is [General Reference](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/presentsimpleorcontinuous/menu.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the verb "to take" is being applied to the noun "technology". In a much simpler form, the sentence would be

> Technology **takes** advantage of (something)

This is still the correct form to use when additional qualifiers and elements of speech are included. Additionally though, I would point out that while many different components of many different cars have changed from mechanical to digital, you are really talking about a single change in *the* technology used to make cars. So I would say instead

> The cars underwent **a** rapid change from the application of mechanical technology to digital, that currently **takes advantage of** artificial intelligence.

**Edit:** Another possibility, that makes one of your initial forms correct in this context, is to say

> ...that **is** currently **taking advantage of**...